# Hibernate is retrieving only one column and other as null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have table categories (cat_id, categoryName) in mysql and I am retrieving its record using hibernate in Spring.

But it is only retrieving cat_id not categoryName

This my category class mapped to table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="categories")
public class Category {
    @Id
    @Column(name="cat_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    
    
    
    @Column(name="categoryName")
    private String categoryName;
    
    public Category() {
        
    }
    public Category(String categoryName) {
        super();
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Category [id=" + id + ", categoryName=" + categoryName + "]";
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
    }
    
}
```

This my controller class which i have used to link to front end

```
public class mainController {

    private CategoryService aCategoryService;
    
    @Autowired
    public mainController(CategoryService a2CategoryService)
    {
        aCategoryService= a2CategoryService;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage(Model theModel)
    {
        List<Category> theCategory= aCategoryService.findall();
        System.out.println(theCategory);
        theModel.addAttribute("categories",theCategory);
        return "index2";
    }
}
```

This is Category Service Implementation interact with repository

```
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    private CategoryRepo categoryRepository;
    @Autowired
    public CategoryServiceImpl(CategoryRepo theCategoryRepo)
    {
        categoryRepository= theCategoryRepo;
    }
    @Override
    public List<Category> findall() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return  categoryRepository.findAll();
        
    }

    @Override
    public Category findById(int theId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Optional<Category> result = categoryRepository.findById(theId);
        Category theCategory= null;
        if (result.isPresent()) {
            theCategory = result.get();
            }
            else {
            // we didn't find the employee                  
            throw new RuntimeException("Did not find category id - " + theId);                  
            }                                   
            return theCategory;             
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Category theCategory) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        categoryRepository.save(theCategory);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(int theId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        categoryRepository.deleteById(theId);
    }

}
```

Also, i am new to Java/Spring/Hibernate
what can i do to solve this issue

console log
Hibernate: select category0_.cat_id as cat_id1_0_, category0_.category_name as category2_0_ from categories category0_
[Category [id=1, categoryName=null], Category [id=2, categoryName=null]]

Comment: can you please add the table create script?

Comment: Do you mean SQL Scripts for creating Table?

Comment: As I understand from your sql, you have to add column name in @column. You have used _ in column name but not in properties in class.

Answer (score 0):

Your database column name is in snake case while your in entity class is in camel case.

So just change the following code

```
@Column(name="categoryName")
private String categoryName;
```

with

```
@Column(name="category_name")
private String categoryName;
```